# Android app display one to many relationship in two different listviews

Tags: android

**XML Link:** http://texudo.zxq.net/GoogleTravelMap/phpsqlajax_genxml.php

**Problem:** Connectivity of two listviews following one to many relationship?

**Question:** 
**Q1.** I am new to android and got task. Please tell me how to extract all hotspots name relavant to each placename and postalcode. 
**Q2.** First listview display placename and postalcode and second listview display hotspot names which will later on proceed to information layout belong to each hotspot name.
**Q3.** If u think my xml service structure is not right then tell me the right one? [Changing tags to attributes]

Looking for suggestions and code examples will be really appreciable. Really needs help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial on parsing xml in android

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: Good toturial. I have to make changes in two classes [RssHandler & AndroidSaxFeedParser].
**Q1:** Class RssHandler? Author is extracting data of <item>...</item>. In my case i have to extract data for <item>...</item> and also for <channel><title><desription>...<item></item></channel>. How i will make endElement and startElement?
**Q2.** Class AndroidSaxFeeParser? How get data of other tags under <channel> tag. Because in this tutorial author is extracting only <item>....</item>.
**Q3.** Message class. Should i include all the data in one class or make 2 classes class hotspot and place?

Comment: you xml is fairly small. use the dom parser and u can get everything you need  by simply iterating the dom object. There are many simple dom parser tutorials out there.